# Hindi fonts not displaying as expected

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to output Hindi font in my Python program, but fonts are not displaying properly. I have tried to decode to utf-8 but no use.

I am using VS Code in Windows 10.

I get this output:

[image: check here the code and output I get]

I am expecting output like this

```
श्रीमान मुख्य अभियंता संदर्भ संख्या
```

Comment: your terminal or your font terminal doesn't support fully Unicode. Ideally it is not to use fully monospace fonts (a mixed fonts).

Comment: `Unifont` works for me…